# Can we get text font and button enabled color for elements in xcuitest

Tags: ios, xcuitest

In the UI we have a some static text and button.

Is it possible to find the font family  used for the text like inter normal.

And for button can we get the colour of the enabled and disabled state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For such tests you should use grey box testing frameworks like EarlGrey2. Good thing about the latter is that its fully compatible with Xcode and XCTest, so you can keep your current code and add some additional checkups.

https://github.com/google/EarlGrey/tree/earlgrey2

Alternatively, you can use screenshot testing. Take a look at SUITCase. This tool allows testing the visual presentation of UI.

https://github.com/devexperts/suitcase